# min-width:320px Not working as intended

Tags: css

In my CSS I have:

```
body {
    min-width:320px;
}
```

Obviously this is meant to prevent elements wrapping or being squashed.

When I size my desktop browser down below 320px the contents are wrapping.

Just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing??

Comment: Seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/vphf9jh0/.  Maybe you could throw together a minimal and complete example for us?

Comment: Try `html, body { min-width:320px; }`

Comment: To add to Ricky_Ruiz, try being more specific with your CSS selector as it may be getting overridden by other rules.

Comment: Resolved by adding the `min-width:320px` to each offending div. Not sure why applying to `html` and `body` is being overridden.